# Inserting html characters into a page title helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

This problem is not critical... but would be helpful for me to know the answer. I've been using Ryan Bates' method of [putting titles on pages](http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title). BTW, he's a great innovator and [contributor](http://railscasts.com) to the rails community, isn't he?

application_helper file:

```
  def title(page_title)
    content_for(:title) { page_title }
  end
```

layout file:

```
<head>
   <title>foo.com - <%= yield(:title) %></title>
   ...
</head>
<body>
   ...
   <h1 class="heading"><%= yield(:title) %></h1>
```

I am trying to manipulate the title to insert more spaces and make one of the words italicized. I thought that if i put the title together as a variable I might be able to do it. I tried inserting `&nbsp;` and that doesn't work. I tried inserting html `<i></i>` and that doesn't work. I would like to get it to look like this:

### First    Second    *Third*

How do I change the code below to make the title look like that?

```
<% ttl = "First Second Third" %>
<% title ttl %>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By HTML syntax, the `title` element content must be plain text, and browsers actually enforce this: the content is rendered as-is, without interpreting anything as HTML tags.

You can have no-break spaces there, but you may need to enter them directly as characters (U+00A0).

You cannot have `<i>` tags there, no matter what technique you use to generate the `title` element.

Comment: @JukkaKorpela, +1 for the info. I have tried a few ways but can't seem to get the syntax right. How would you insert a unicode character into the title string? I have tried <% ttl = "First" + (U+00A0) + "Second" + (U+00A0) + "Third" %> and <% ttl = "Discern (U+00A0) Validate (U+00A0) Align" %> Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

by default rails escapes the html while rendering string on view, you need to mark it safe using html_safe to avoid escaping.

following code should resolve your problem

```
<% ttl = "First &nbsp;&nbsp; Second &nbsp;&nbsp; <i>Third</i>" %>
<% title ttl.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. In the rails helper it is rendered "First &nbsp;&nbsp; Second &nbsp;&nbsp; <i>Third</i>"